# Solidity - Identifier not found or not unique onlyOwner()

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, solidity

I'm getting the following truffle compile error when running `truffle compile`:

```
DeclarationError : Identifier not found or not unique.
   --> project:/contracts/TestCoin.sol:183:56:
    |
183 |     function excludeFromRewards(address account) public onlyOwner() {
    |
```

I have the following code inside of my Token contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";

contract TestCoin is ERC20 {

    constructor(_name, _symbol) {
        _name = name();
        _symbol = symbol();
    }

    .......

    function excludeFromRewards(address account) public onlyOwner() {
        .......
    }

    .......
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? I can't seem to get past this and I'm importing the `Ownable.sol` file, so I'm confused as to why this is happening. Do I need to be saying using Ownable as blah for anything that is imported? I would assume that it would just inherit those imports.

**Update**:

If I call the owner function which is located in the ownable.sol, I get the same error.

```
if(owner() == msg.sender)

Undeclared identifier.
if(owner() == msg.sender)
   ^^^^^
```

It seems that it doesn't recognize that file. Any thoughts as to why?

**Update #2**:

I figured it out and posted my solution below. Thanks!

Comment: could you eidtar and add all your code?
In what I see it is importing other contracts, but "TestCoin" is not inheriting them

Comment: I have added everything above the construct that I left out. The rest of the code below the construct are just custom functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I needed to inject Ownable into the contract itself so it would be available.

```
contract TestCoin is ERC20, Ownable {
    *********
}
```